# Master-detail layout on Android

Tags: android, layout, master-detail

I have an app, and one of the tabs has a Task List. My intention is, when I click in one of the elements of that list, I want to see the detais of that task. Is it possible to view the list and the details of that task in the same page ? Im using Eclipse.

Comment: The best solution is to use Fragments http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

You can either code it yourself by fooling around with views and their visibility/sizes.
Or you can use Fragments : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

yon can open a `PopupWindow` on listview item click and show details of selected item. for  open a `PopupWindow` on item  click [see](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.in/2010/04/popupwindow-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you dont want to use fragments (for example you wont ever be reusing this view) you could also do this - easy and simple:

This would be your split screen layout splitscreen.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/task_list_wrap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/task_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="never" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/task_details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/task_details_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="this is description text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And you would change the content of task details panel when clicked on task list like this in your activity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.splitscreen);
ListView taskList= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.task_list);
TextView taskDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.task_details_description);
taskList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        int selectedTask = position;
        updateTaskDescription(selectedTask, taskDescription);
    }
});
```